# Attribute chipText not found

Tags: android, material-components, mdc-components, material-components-android

I am using Material Chips from the Material Design Component library released by Google for Android. But when I updated the `com.google.android.material:material` to version `1.0.0-rc01`, I have started to get the error in the below line.

```
app:chipText="@string/chip_morning"
```

The error that I am getting is attribute chipText not found.

I have tried replacing it with `android:text="@string/chip_morning"` but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest dependency, cause, now you can use `android:text` xml attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **`1.0.0-rc01`**, You should try with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

Make sure that the repositories section includes Google’s Maven repository **`google()`**.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
  }
```

Comment: @MehulKanzariya gradle version?

Comment: Gradle Version: 3.3.0-alpha05

Comment: @MehulKanzariya could you downgrade version for test case.use stable version instead of alpha.

Comment: Okay. Also, I noticed one thing. If I change line app:chipText to android:text and rebuild the project, it again changes to the app:chipText. What should be the reason behind that?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Didn't face this. `app:chipText` is default that's why probably set.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Solved this yet?

Comment: No, still finding the solution.

Comment: Solved. I was removing the chipText attribute from the debug file so it was getting added automatically.